Cohomology and Hopf theorem
The famous Hopf-Whitney theorem states that if $Y$ is any $(n-1)$ - connected space with $\pi=\pi_n(Y)$ and $X$ is any $n$-dimensional $C W$ complex, then the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi:[X, Y] & \rightarrow H^n(X ; \pi) \\
{[f] } & \rightarrow f^*(\iota)
\end{aligned}
$$
is a bijective correspondence.
This theorem is most often used in the context of manifolds, where it implies that if $M^n$ is any closed, orientable manifold the correspondence
$$
[M^n, S^n] \leftrightarrow H^n(M^n ; \mathbb{Z})
$$
is a bijection.

My two questions are the following: suppose now I have $K^{n+1}$ an $n+1$ complex.

Can I still say that any element $H^n(K^{n+1} ; \mathbb{Z})$ is represented by an equivalence class of mappings from $K$ to an $n-1$-connected space like $S^n$?
Do I still have a bijection or is it just a surjection between any cohomology class in $H^n(K^{n+1} ; \mathbb{Z})$ and any element in $[K^{n+1}, S^n]$?

If $K^{n+1}$ is the $n+1$ sphere, I get $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)$ and I want to see its relations with $H^n(S^{n+1})$. The latter is trivial, while the former almost never. This makes me think about the existence of a surjection, in the sense that for every cohomology class $H^n(K^{n+1})$ there exist an element in $[K^{n+1}, S^n]$ representing it.

What do you think? Please show us some work.

Hint: You may want to think about $K = S^{n + 1}$ and look up a table of homotopy groups of spheres.

You should justify why you think this and update the question with your thoughts (e.g. work out some examples; in particular think about the hint I gave). We don't generally accept questions on this site that don't show some own effort in solving their problems. On another note, could you please clarify whether you're asking for there to be a $(n - 1)$-connected spaces representing $H^n(K^{n + 1})$ in question 1 or whether you want this to hold for all such spaces?

Your first question can be rephrased as follows.

Can we find an $(n-1)$-connected space $Y$ such that there is a bijective correspondence between $H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$ and $[K^{n+1}, Y]$ for any $(n+1)$-dimensional CW complex $K^{n+1}$?

The short answer to this question is yes. You can take the Eilenberg-MacLane space $Y=K(\Bbb Z,n)$. This gives you a natural isomorphism $[X,K(\Bbb Z,n)]\cong H^n(X;\Bbb Z)$ when $X$ is any CW complex, not necessarily $(n+1)$-dimensional.
However, $K(\Bbb Z,n)$ is not easy to describe in general, so I guess it makes sense to ask the following question.

If we only care about $(n+1)$-dimensional complexes, do we have a choice for $Y$ that is easier to describe?

Yes. We can take $Y=S^1$ if $n=1$ and $Y=\Sigma^{n-2}\Bbb CP^2$ [the $(n-2)$-fold reduced suspension of $\Bbb CP^2$] if $n\ge 2$.
Assume $n\ge 2$ since $S^1$ is a $K(\Bbb Z,1)$. Let $Y$ be built from $S^n$ by attaching $(n+2)$-cells which kill elements in $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)$. More explicitly, for $n\ge 2$, $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)$ is generated by the $(n-2)$-fold suspension of Hopf map $\eta$, so $Y=C(\Sigma^{n-2}\eta)$ is the mapping cone of $\Sigma^{n-2}\eta$. By considering the long exact sequence of homotopy groups associated with the pair $(Y,S^n)$, we see that $Y$ is $(n-1)$-connected, $\pi_n(Y)\cong\pi_n(S^n)$, and $\pi_{n+1}(Y)=0$.
Now, we can attach cells of dimension at least $n+3$ to kill higher homotopy groups of $Y$ and "eventually" arrive at $K(\Bbb Z,n)$. So $Y$ is essentially the $(n+2)$-skeleton of $K(\Bbb Z,n)$.
We now claim that $$H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)\cong[K^{n+1},K(\Bbb Z,n)]\overset{\sim}{\underset{i_\ast}{\longleftarrow}}[K^{n+1},K(\Bbb Z,n)^{(n+2)}]=[K^{n+1},Y]$$
It suffices to prove the bijection in the middle. The map $i_\ast:[K^{n+1},Y]\to [K^{n+1},K(\Bbb Z,n)]$ is induced by the inclusion $i:Y\to K(\Bbb Z,n)$. The surjectivity of $i_\ast$ follows directly from of cellular approximation theorem; injectivity follows from the fact that if $H:K^{n+1}\times I\to K(\Bbb Z,n)$ is a homotopy between two (cellular) maps then cellular approximation (for pairs) implies that $H$ is homotopic to a cellular map $G:K^{n+1}\times I\to K(\Bbb Z,n)^{(n+2)}=Y$ rel $K^{n+1}\times \{0,1\}$.
Therefore, we get a natural bijection between $H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$ and $[K^{n+1}, Y]$, where $Y=C(\Sigma^{n-2}\eta)$. We have $C(\Sigma^{n-2}\eta)\cong \Sigma^{n-2}C(\eta)\cong\Sigma^{n-2}\Bbb CP^2$, so the natural bijection can be written as
$$[K^{n+1},\Sigma^{n-2}\Bbb CP^2]\cong H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$$
This works when $K^{n+1}$ is any CW complex with dimension at most $n+1$ and $n\ge 2$.

The answer to your 2nd question is that we always have a surjection from $[K^{n+1},S^n]$ to $H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$ for any $(n+1)$-dim complex. Note that the $(n+1)$-skeleton of $K(\Bbb Z,n)$ is $K(\Bbb Z,n)^{(n+1)}=S^n$ because no $(n+1)$-cells are attached in the process of killing higher homotopy groups. By cellular approximation theorem, any continuous map $f:K^{n+1}\to K(\Bbb Z,n)$ is homotopic to a cellular map $\tilde{f}:K^{n+1}\to K(\Bbb Z,n)^{(n+1)}=S^n$, so the map $$j_\ast:[K^{n+1},S^n]\longrightarrow [K^{n+1},K(\Bbb Z,n)]\cong H^n(K^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$$ induced by the inclusion $S^n\subseteq K(\Bbb Z,n)$ is surjective.

@Porcupine It depends on what you mean by "no way to make it a bijection".  What your counterexample $S^{n+1}$ shows is that those two groups are not in bijective correspondence in general. However, that does not mean they can never be isomorphic. For example, if I take $K^{n+1}=D^{n+1}$, then $H^n(D^{n+1})=0$ and $[D^{n+1},S^n]=0$ since the disk is contractible.

@Porcupine So, your counterexample of $K^{n+1}=S^{n+1}$ is sufficient to show that those two groups are not always isomorphic. In particular, it implies that you cannot find a natural isomorphism between them. The last paragraph of my answer shows that there is always a surjection $[K,S^n]\to H^n(K^{n+1})$.

Yes sorry. By no way I meant that "in general" they are not isomorphic, but there is always a surjection. Thank you very much!!

Fwiw, one can actually determine $[K^{n + 1}, S^n]$ fully: it is in natural bijection to  $H^n(K^{n + 1}; \mathbb{Z}) \times \operatorname{coker} \phi$ where $\phi$ is the composite $H^{n - 1}(K^{n + 1}; \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\text{mod } 2} H^{n - 1}(K^{n + 1}; \mathbb{Z} / 2) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{Sq}^2} H^{n + 1}(K^{n + 1}; \mathbb{Z} / 2)$ (at least when $n \geq 3$), as per this answer. In particular this set has a natural group structure.

@BenSteffan Actually, I read this wonderful answer earlier today, haha. It was quite surprising to me that this cohomotopy set has such an elegant description using cohomology operations. Thanks for linking it to this thread.
